# Inline keyword without higher-order function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inline

There's `listOf()` function in `Collections.kt` found in Kotlin source code.

```
/**
 * Returns an empty read-only list.  The returned list is serializable (JVM).
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Lists.emptyReadOnlyList
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> listOf(): List<T> = emptyList()
```

What is the benefit or purpose of `inline` keyword with a function which is not a higher-order function? How lack of this keyword would introduce runtime overhead at call-sites?

Comment: Just a guess...inlining non-higher-order functions can result in more duplicated bytecode in the project so it can be harmful, but not if the function does nothing but pass through the call to another function. This might be some kind of micro-optimization to save the runtime from having to inline it (as it probably would), or to save Proguard/R8 an inlining step each time they're encountered.